# Prohibit printing, saving, copy and clipboard for the user

Tags: security, documents

I'd like to restrict my users to print, save, copy and make a screenshot of some really sensitive data. The current situation is a simple PDF which prohibits saving and printing but allows making a screenshot and simple right- click in the browser windows and execute "save as". Also, it is an issue that the PDF get's temporary stored in the filesystem means the user is able to copy that PDF which should only be allowed to be accessed through the webbrowser.

**To sum it up what I want:**

- Prevent printing
- Prevent saving
- Prevent screenshots (clipboard)

**This is what can be ignored:**

- Make a picture from telephone/ camera

As far as I know, PDFs do not deliver such an amount of security. Especially since some users have their own installation of a PDF reader - making any use of Adobe restrictions useless.

Since I'm only searching for possibilities to archive my goal, there's no limit in costs.

**Here are the things we thought about already:**

- Seperate machines for each user with a specific security areas
- Some kind of Flash streaming (wouldn't really match those requirements)
- A new application with database to handle it separately

That's pretty much everything. While the option to create an own application pretty much smiles at me, I'd like to hear your thoughts and ideas to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can't prevent screenshots unless you gain full control over the operating system. From within a browser or PDF/PDF reader, this can not be achieved.

Comment: I think the question is too broad, and off-topic for StackOverflow. It is just general advice about how to achieve this, not necessarily a software solution. You are also looking for recommendations of tools and stuff. No offense intended - just being blunt. It could be a good fit for security.SE if you rephrased it a bit. Made it more focused on techniques for secured document viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise that you have a look at [this - a Guide to PDF Security](http://www.drumlinsecurity.com/PDFSecurity.pdf), which suggests [LockLizard](http://www.locklizard.com/) and [Drumlin Javelin Security Suite](http://www.drumlinsecurity.com/index.html), both of which do exactly what you are after, including a capability to prevent screenshots. [Adobe Digital Editions](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/digital-editions.html) is another possible answer, but is made more for publishers than secure or sensitive data.

Comment: LockLizard looks exactly what I look for, thanks for this!
Any other way which wouldn't include a PDF solution?